# rdpsign corrupts RDP file

Tags: rdp

We want to programmatically generate RDP files and sign them to try to get rid of any prompts when establishing the RDP connection (the system consuming the RDP files is for automation).  When we create a test RDP file, then sign it with rdpsign (passing the hash/thumbprint), we get the standard success message from rdpsign.  However, when you execute the signed RDP file, you get an "ERROR: This RDP file is corrupted. The remote connection cannot be started." message.

We are using Windows 7 x64 system (AzureRM VM from the gallery).  Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of certificate did you use? Is that certificate in the trusted root store?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by removing the following options from the RDP file before signing:

- `rdgiskdcproxy`
- `kdcproxyname`

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4166425a-6f9d-4de5-a776-145b3da72f2c/rdp-files-signed-with-rdpsign-became-corrupted-in-rdp-80